# Validate Modal Form

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to popup a form so user fill it then I save that record. If data is wrong I want to inform the user just a classic validation issue.

I am trying this code but when model is not valid it show the mistake but literally it only returns what is in the partial view, it is not loading my layout nor my modal form, all I get is a white page just with my partial.

so what am I doing wrong?

This is my modal form:

[image]

And after validation all I get is this:

[image]

Code:
Model:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Car</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @Html.Partial("CreatePartialView",new Car())
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="savechanges">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

my partial:

```
@model ControliBootstrap.Models.Car

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ModalAdd", "Cars",new AjaxOptions()
{
UpdateTargetId = "mymodalform"
}))
{
<div class="form-horizontal" id="mymodalform">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Brand, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Brand)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Brand)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Year, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Year)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Year)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Color, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Color)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Color)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

and finlly my controler:

```
 public ActionResult ModalAdd(Car car)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Cars.Add(car);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return PartialView("CreatePartialView",car);
    }
```

Comment: Have you definitely included jQuery unobtrusive AJAX?

Comment: Im a f* moron thanks very much that solved the problem

Comment: I'll post it as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to include [jQuery Unobtrusive AJAX](http://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Ajax.Unobtrusive/) - it's the library that makes normal HTML forms have some AJAX capabilities.

Comment: Do you know why my ajax call stops working after the first time?, if I set replace as insertion method my new button is doing exactly the same mistake I had before, Then I set addafter as insertion method and  only the first button works, all the ones who were insterted after, redirect me to the mistake I had before

Comment: The partial includes the form. This means that when a replace occurs the form is being placed inside a form which is not valid HTML. Try putting the _id_ on a `div` that wraps around the form.

Comment: 1 more question please, in my controller when model is not valid I am getting the Index view inside my modal, how do I end it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. You might have to ask a new question.